# Search multiple tables and add results to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

As an exercise I was given a project with three tables Booking, Room and Host. The models are as follows:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :host
  has_many :bookings
end

class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
end
```

The database schema looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150305133000) do

  create_table "bookings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "room_id",          null: false
    t.date     "start_date",       null: false
    t.date     "end_date",         null: false
    t.integer  "number_of_guests", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "hosts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "picture_url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "rooms", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "host_id",    null: false
    t.integer  "capacity",   null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

I need to implement a search feature that returns all hosts with rooms available between dates specified by the search form. To find hosts that are available for the required dates I need to cross reference with the Bookings table.

I skimmed through [the ruby guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and also had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380775/rails-beginner-best-practice-for-querying-multiple-tables-to-retrieve-lots-of) but I'm having trouble implementing what I've read.

In the rails console I've been playing around with varying queries to try and get the results I need.

If I let `@bookings = Booking.includes(:room).all` and `@hosts = []` and if `start_date`, `end_date` and `guests` are parameters returned from he search then running the following query:

```
@bookings.each { |b| @hosts.push(b.room.host) if (b.start_date < start_date && b.end_date > end_date && (b.room.capacity - b.number_of_guests >= guests)) }
```

produces an empty `@hosts`. I then tried

```
 Booking.joins(:room).where("start_date < ? AND end_date > ? and capacity-number_of_guests >= ?", start_date, end_date, guests)
```

But that also returned and empty response so then I tried to do this in baby steps by finding all the bookings for the requested dates, filtering out the rooms that didn't have any space and then gathering together all the hosts of the rooms that were left. I got as far as:

```
@bookings = Booking.where("start_date = ? AND end_date >= ?",
  Date.parse(params[:start_date]),
  Date.parse(params[:end_date])).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

@bookings.reject{ |booking| (booking.room.capacity - booking.number_of_guests) == 0 }
```

However, this is still returning empty rooms. I've been at this for over a day now so if anyone can point me in the right direction towards getting this solved I'd appreciate it!

### **DEBUGGING ATTEMPTS**

Following denis-bu's suggestions I've updated my first query to read (leaving the room capacity alone for the time being):

```
@bookings.each { |b| @hosts.push(b.room.host) if ((b.start_date > start_date &&
  b.start_date < end_date) || (b.end_date > start_date && b.end_date < end_date)) }
```

I've run this in the rails console and when I then try `@hosts.count` it returns `0` - so that implies the query isn't fetching any results. I'd expect to see an array of `Host` records.

Comment: Can you update your question with some column names that you would be using?

Comment: I've add the db schema to the question - hope that helps!

Comment: Do you need just hosts or rooms as well for that query?

Comment: @Eugzol I need both hosts and rooms - I want to display all the hosts that have rooms available plus room information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really enough details of what you're trying to achieve, but I'd make a guess that prolem is with your condition: `start_date < ? AND end_date > ?` - checks that query dates within booking interval, instead you should check that booking overlaps with your query dates: `((b.start_date > START_DATE and b.start_date < END_DATE) OR
          (b.end_date > START_DATE and b.end_date < END)`.

BUT, I'd say that is not all you should do. You should also find rooms without bookings for query dates and then union those sets.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have a much better idea of how to go about this. All I'm trying to do is let users put two dates and the number of guests into a search form then display hosts that have rooms available for those dates. For the moment, I'm trying to work with the rooms with bookings before moving onto those without. I've restructured my query as per your suggestions but `@hosts` is still empty after I run it.  I've narrowed down the problem to the start and end date part of the query but I have no idea where I'm going wrong. Any more ideas?

Comment: please, post code that you're trying to debug (i.e. after you've changed dates condition) and which records you expect to retreive from database against query dates

Comment: so, code looks right. my point is: manually find one booking that you expect to find. then check if this booking is in @bookings. if it is, then check why condition is false... e.g. you can parse dates wrong..

Comment: e.g. bb = Booking.find(42) # 42 is id of booking you expect to be in reqults of the query.  then check what ```((bb.start_date > start_date &&
  bb.start_date < end_date) || (bb.end_date > start_date && bb.end_date < end_date))```  gives you. then checck why, : check what  ```(bb.start_date > start_date &&
  bb.start_date < end_date)``` gives you ... etc. thus you can narrow down where it fails, find root cause and fix it :).

Comment: This has got me on the right track, especially the reminder to check for rooms without booking. Now I just need to figure out how to filter the results! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

With my [Where Exists](https://github.com/eugzol/where_exists) gem and PostgreSQL:

```
Room.includes(:host).where_not_exists(:bookings,
 [
   "(?, ?) OVERLAPS (start_date, end_date)",
   params[:start_date],
   params[:end_date]
 ]
)
```

Without the gem:

```
# Using PostgreSQL OVERLAPS (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html)

overlaps = Booking.where(where("(?, ?) OVERLAPS (start_date, end_date)", start_date, end_date))

# With MySQL or SQLite you should check for boundaries manually

overlaps = Booking.where("? < end_date", start_date).where("? > start_date", end_date)

Room.includes(:host).where("NOT EXISTS (#{
  overlaps.where("bookings.room_id = rooms.id").to_sql
})")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's good to know such a gem exists and I probably will use it in future however I think the aim of this exercise is to get comfortable querying databases so I'd prefer to solve this 'manually' for now :)

Comment: @SoSimple I've updated my answer with version of the query which doesn't use gem :)

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error: `SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms"  WHERE (NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"  WHERE (booking.room_id = room.id) AND (('2015-06-01', '2015-06-07') OVERLAPS (start_date, end_date))))
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms"  WHERE (NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"  WHERE (booking.room_id = room.id) AND (('2015-06-01', '2015-06-07') OVERLAPS (start_date, end_date))))`

Comment: Also, I'm storing the start and end date in the `start_date` and `end_date` variables

Comment: Good solution. This of course returns the rooms themselves -- I guess that if you just wanted the hosts, and wanted to do so in the most efficient way, you'd want it constructed as "select hosts where exists (a room where not exists (a booking for this period))". I like the gem -- can it do that sort of nested (not) exists

Comment: @DavidAldridge The gem can do nested queries, but not that particular kind ('exists' + 'NOT exists'). Please create an issue on the GitHub with that example, I'll share my thoughts on that.

Comment: @SoSimple As I've written in my answer (in code comments), `OVERLAPS` only works for Postgres. You are using SQLite, you should replace that single `where` with manual interval check. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @EugZol oh! Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: @SoSimple Updated my answer :)